# Spectral radius is not matrix norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-radius

I have seen an example of matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1  \\
   0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}$$

whose spectral radius is zero therefore the spectral radius is not matrix norm. Why the spectral radius is not matrix norm in this case Is it possible that $\|A\|=\epsilon$?

Comment: You can conjugate $A$ to $\pmatrix{0&\epsilon\\0&0}$.

Comment: what is $\rho$?

Comment: @mathreadler its spectral radius.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown why I conjugate A to that matrix?

Comment: @Tien his point is that $\rho(\epsilon A) = \rho(A)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom how does it affects the Lemma?

Comment: @Tien Note that $|||\epsilon A||| = |\epsilon|\cdot |||A||||$.  Your lemma is false.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Does it mean that $|||A|||=\epsilon$

Answer (score 17):

You seem to have confused spectral radius with spectral norm. The word *spectral* in *spectral norm* actually refers *not* to the spectrum of $A$, but to the spectrum of $A^\ast A$. In my opinion, we should all abandon this misleading name, but adopt the more appropriate name, the *operator norm*, instead.

The operator norm $\|A\|_2$ is defined by
$$
\max_{\|x\|_2\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=\max_{\|u\|_2=1}\|Au\|_2.\tag{1}
$$
It is identical to the largest **singular value**, i.e. the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^\ast A$.

Unlike spectral radius, the operator norm is defined for all square or non-square complex matrices. The norm can be more accurately called the spectral norm when $A$ is square and self-adjoint. In that case, the operator norm coincides with the spectral radius, and the spectral radius is a (submultiplicative) norm on the real linear space of all self-adjoint matrices.

The operator norm is always bounded below by the spectral radius, but as your example shows, the two quantities can be unequal. Your $A$ is nonzero in the first place, so its norm cannot possibly be zero. Using the equivalent definition on the RHS of $(1)$, or the singular value of $A$, it is not hard to show that $\|A\|_2=1$.

Square matrices whose operator norms equal their spectral radii are called *radial*. The name originates from the fact that the equality of $\|A\|_2$ and $\rho(A)$ is equivalent to the equality of $\|A\|_2$ and $r(A)=\max_{\|u\|=1}|\langle Au,u\rangle|$, the *numerical radius* of $A$. Radial matrices includes normal matrices as subclass, while the latter includes self-adjoint matrices as an even smaller subclass.

Comment: The spectral radius is only equal to the largest eigenvalue when the matrix is symmetric

Comment: @information_interchange No. When $A$ is real symmetric, the spectral radius is always equal to the magnitude of the largest-sized eigenvalue, but not necessarily equal to the largest eigenvalue. E.g. when $A=\operatorname{diag}(0,-1)$, we have $\rho(A)=1\ne0=\lambda_\max(A)$.

Answer (score 6):

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) Wikipedia page, the spectral norm of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is defined as

$$\rho\left(A\right)=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\left\{\left|\lambda_{i}\right|\right\}$$

where the $\lambda_{i}$'s are the eigenvalues of the matrix. In your case

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

is triangular, so the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues. Thus you have $\lambda_{1}=\lambda_{2}=0$, and it follows immediately that

$$\rho\left(A\right)=0$$

This is not a norm since $A\neq 0$ and a norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ must satisfy

> $$\left\|A\right\|=0\:\Longleftrightarrow\: A=0$$

by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Define the norm $\| A \|_L = \|V_L^{-1} A V_L\|$
where
$V_L = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & {1 \over L}\end{bmatrix}$.

Note that $\lim_{L \to \infty} V_L^{-1} A V_L = 0$

**Addendum**:

Note that the above norm is an induced norm. If we let
$\|x\|_L = \|V_L^{-1} x\|$ then
$\|A\|_L = \sup_{\|x\|_L \le 1} \|Ax\|_L$.

**Another addendum** (the question changed):

With $U_L=\begin{bmatrix} L & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ show
that $\lim_{L \downarrow 0} \|U_L^{-1} A U_L\| = 0$ and
$\lim_{L \to \infty} \|U_L^{-1} A U_L\| = \infty$.

Now, for any $r>0$ use the intermediate value theorem to choose some $L$ such that 
$\|U_L^{-1} A U_L \| = r$.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question

Comment: Choose $L$ large enough so that $\|A\|_L < \epsilon$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Am I missing something?

Comment: that doesn't disprove of a norm such that $\rho(A) \leq |||A|||\leq  \rho(A)+\epsilon$ for some fixed $\epsilon$.  If you took $L \to )^+$, on the other hand, that would accomplish what we want.

Comment: It doesn't disprove anything. It exhibits a norm such that $0=\rho(A) \le \|A\|_L \le \rho(A)+ \epsilon = \epsilon$.

Comment: oh! I misinterpreted the question.  I thought they were asking for a norm $|||\cdot|||$ such that *for all A* (and a fixed epsilon), then inequality holds.  This all makes sense now.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I need to add some clarification to my answer. The norm I specified is an induced norm, but it not obvious above.

Comment: @copper.hat does $0=\rho(A)\leq ‖A‖_L\leq \rho(A)+\epsilon=\epsilon$ means that $ |||A|||=\epsilon$? or can we just say that a matrix with zero spectral radius has $ |||A|||=\epsilon$?

Comment: No, it says that for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find an induced norm $n$ such that  $n(A) \in [\rho(A),\rho(A)+\epsilon]$.

Comment: @copper.hat So if we have a matrix say $X$ with spectral radius zero then is it possible that $|||X|||=\epsilon$?

Comment: @Tien: I don't  really understand what you are asking. The result says that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a norm such that $|||X||| \le \epsilon$.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean. What is $\epsilon$? In general, you can't find a norm that equals a specific value, take $X=0$ then any norm will be zero.